# jQuery deferred array not triggering .done() as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I'm having some trouble with jQuery deferreds.  Here's my code:

```
function makeAjaxCalls(purge){
  var deferreds = [];
  // delete the documents
  _.each(purge, function(element, index, list){
    console.log('purging '+element.model+' id='+element.id);
    deferreds.push(
      $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '/API/admin/purge/'+element.model+'/'+element.id
      })
    );
  });
  console.log('returning array with '+deferreds.length+' deferreds');
  return deferreds;
};

function purgeDeletedDocs(){
  console.log('purging...');
  var purge = [];
  _.each(arrayOfIDs, function(element, index, list){
    purge.push({'model': arrayOfModels.get(element).get('modelName'), 'id': element});
  }); // [{model: 'modelName', id: 'id'}...]
  // when *all* the AJAX calls are resolved run this code
  $.when.apply(this, deferreds).done(function(){
    console.log('done');
  });
  var deferreds = makeAjaxCalls(purge);
};

purgeDeletedDocs()
```

As you can see I'm using `$.when.apply` as I'm returning an array of deferreds from the `makeAjaxCalls()` function.

Here's what I'm getting in the console:

```
purging...
done
purging User id=5564e0f647f054512a9d64c9
purging Client id=557079a04407058a49fd2f3d
returning array with 2 deferreds
```

Now that's odd.  I'm seeing the `done` before the AJAX calls have been even made, let alone resolved.  I'm passing `this` into the `apply()` but using `$` etc. makes no difference - and reading the docs for `apply()` the first parameter just sets the `this` for the code so that's the expected behaviour.

The server is correctly getting the API calls made so the AJAX calls are being made, it's just that the multiple deferreds seem to resolve and trigger the `.done()` before they're even made.

Any ideas as to what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You appear to be calling `makeAjaxCalls(purge)` ***after*** you call `$.when.apply($, deferreds)`?

Comment: your definition of deferreds come after the when this means that the promises resolved immediately - and that means that it is called before the actual request is made fro akeAjaxCalls(purge);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> // when *all* the AJAX calls are resolved run this code
> $.when.apply(this, deferreds).done(function(){
>     console.log('done');
> });
> var deferreds = makeAjaxCalls(purge);
> ```
>
> As you can see I'm using `$.when.apply` as I'm returning an array of
>   deferreds from the `makeAjaxCalls()` function.

Well but you're not passing them into the `$.when` function. Instead, you are passing `undefined` to `$.when`, even before making that call to `makeAjaxCalls()`!

Reorder your statements to

```
var deferreds = makeAjaxCalls(purge);
$.when.apply(this, deferreds).done(function(){
    console.log('done');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bergi. *facepalm* I've been staring at this screen too long today... wood, trees etc.